# Is it ok to have style tag and xml in svg embedded in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have generated some svgs with Adobe Illustrator and have embedded them inline in my html page. As far as I know all `style` tags must be in head but these svgs have their own `style` tags. Following is the example of one svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 526.6 28.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 526.6 28.3;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0 {
        fill: none;
        }

        .st1 {
        enable-background: new;
        }

        .st2 {
        fill: #009444;
        }
    </style>
    <rect y="2.3" class="st0" width="526.6" height="26" />
</svg>
```

The svg renders well in Firefox and Chrome. One svg appeared smaller than in other browsers in IE11 and Edge it appeared perfect. I haven't checked in Safari as I don't have mac. My question is:

- Is it ok to have style tag and xml in svg embedded in html page as per w3c and browser compatibility?

P.S: In a work of mine I saw problems with inline svg in EDGE browser when appended with jquery `appendTo`. The svgs, set to display inline-block   overlapped each other. (The bottom case in https://anupamkhosla.github.io/marqueedirection/)

Comment: It is ok to have both inline svg and css. I would suggest to group all your styles at the head of the html document but anyway it's valid html.

Comment: @DavidLamponDiestre Actually svgs are added from server side. We add new images and the backend logic replaces `img` tags with inline svgs. And I also noticed `xml` tag is automatically commented out by the browsers.

Comment: I think a little bit of cleaning should be done in the BE before injecting the svg into the html to reduce the data sent for a better scenario. Although the final composition might not be the best (as I'd prefer at least to have all inline styles together in head) it's valid w3c to have inline svg and css.

Comment: If you concern about W3C, did you check your page with W3C validators? http://validator.w3.org for HTML and https://jigsaw.w3.org for CSS.

Comment: @ata Yes just checked now. The only error I got is _"text inside svg tag isn't allowed"_. In actual page I had _Sorry your browser don't support svg_ inside the svg tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer MDN for these kinds of standards. As it is given in [their SVG style page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style), you can use and it is valid to have `<style>`
tag inside SVG.

Comment: MDN is not the place to look for a standard. It is developer documentation. The [SVG standard is maintained by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an HTML document, but an SVG document.

In SVG, there is no `<head>` element and [`<style>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StyleElement) is commonly placed directly in the root elements or in a `<defs>` subelement.

As [documented in the HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#svg), you can embed whole SVG documents in HTML, including `<style>`. Therefore, **it is ok to place `style` into SVG documents within HTML ones**, provided they are actually SVG, i.e. their namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`.

In HTML, `<style>` should be put under `<head>` (or `<noscript>` in `<head>`), per [the HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element).

Comment: I didn't mean a `head` tag inside `svg` tag. I meant that the `style` tag that is already inside `svg` tag is seen inside `body` tag of the containing html document. And as far as I know `style` tag inside `body` is not valid.

Comment: I have amended the answer. Commonly, `style` is indeed put under head, but I cannot find any indication that style in body is invalid. Can you provide a reference to the standard that says so?

Comment: I tested in w3c validator. Putting `style` inside `body` gives error. I remember this because I some time ago I was reading about scoped style.

Comment: The w3c official referenced you linked says: _Contexts in which this element can be used:
Where metadata content is expected._ And afaik metadata is expected in head tag.

Comment: @user31782 Oh, you are correct, `<style>` is only supposed to be in head. I have updated the answer. Note that `where metadata content is expected` has a [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#metadata-content-0), but unfortunately it's not overly precise.

Comment: It could be that `metadata` is also expected in `svg` tags.